# Validar 2 mayusculas con una expresion regular

Tags: javascript, regex, validación

estoy haciendo un validador de contraseñas y quiero que tenga 2 letras mayusculas pero sin importar el orden de estas, es decir, si ingresa AbcdE debería ser valido.
Ahora solo tengo esta expresion `[A-Z]{2,}` pero no me funciona el todo, si ingreso lo que puse mas arriba me marca false, como podría hacer para reconocer las mayusculas a lo largo de la cadena?

De la misma forma quiero validar que tenga mas de 8 caracteres, 5 numeros, etc.

Este es mi código:

````
    var text = document.getElementById('password').value;

    var length = document.getElementById('length');
    var lowercase = document.getElementById('lowercase');
    var uppercase = document.getElementById('uppercase');
    var number = document.getElementById('number');
    var special = document.getElementById('special');
    var repeat = document.getElementById('repeat');

    checkIfEightChar(text) ? length.classList.add('list-group-item-success') : length.classList.remove('list-group-item-success');
    checkIfOneLowercase(text) ? lowercase.classList.add('list-group-item-success') : lowercase.classList.remove('list-group-item-success');
    checkIfUppercase(text) ? uppercase.classList.add('list-group-item-success') : uppercase.classList.remove('list-group-item-success');
    checkIfDigit(text) ? number.classList.add('list-group-item-success') : number.classList.remove('list-group-item-success');
    checkIfOneSpecialChar(text) ? special.classList.add('list-group-item-success') : special.classList.remove('list-group-item-success');
    //validaCaracteresSeguidos(text) ? repeat.classList.add('list-group-item-success') : repeat.classList.remove('list-group-item-success');
}

function checkIfEightChar(text){
    return text.length >= 8;
}

function checkIfOneLowercase(text) {
    return /[a-z]/.test(text);
}

function checkIfUppercase(text) {
    return /[A-Z]{2,}/g.test(text);
}

function checkIfDigit(text) {
    return /[0-9]{5,}/.test(text);
}

function checkIfOneSpecialChar(text) {
    return /[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(text);
} ```
````

Comment: Seguro que debes de tener un limite de caracteres para esa contraseña, no creo que tu validador, acepte 1000 caracteres para una contraseña o 3, proporciona esa informacion por favor.

Comment: ¿Tu contraseña puede permitir saltos de linea `\n`?

Comment: disculpa, ahora actualicé la pregunta y agregué todo el código, gracias por tu comentario, estaré atento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola con esta sola expreción regular puede resolver el problema

```js
const correcta = "P55p544P3*43"
const incorrecta1 = "aaa"
const incorrecta2 = "aa34a"
const incorrecta3 = "aa*Pa"
const incorrecta4 = "aPaP*678a"

function check(text) {
    return /^(?=.*((\S*\d){5,}))(?=.*((\S*[A-Z]){2,}))(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\W])\S{8,}$/.test(text);
}

console.log(check(correcta))
console.log(check(incorrecta1))
console.log(check(incorrecta2))
console.log(check(incorrecta3))
console.log(check(incorrecta4))
```

explico por partes:

1- `^` Inicio de la expreción

2-`(?=.*((\S*\d){5,}))` - en esta parte me aseguro que tenga núemeros la expreción usando `?=` *positive lookahead assertion* y `((\S*\d){5,})` con esta expreción valido que sean núemros los que se busquen `\d` se encarga de eso ahora, `\S*\d` es para que los números no tengan que estar consecutivos y `{5,}` es para que como mínimo sean 5

3- `(?=.*((\S*[A-Z]){2,}))` tiene el mismo objetivo que el anterior solo que en vez de buscar núemros buscamos mayúsculas con `[A-Z]`

4- `(?=.*[a-z])` es para que al menos tenga una minúscula

5- `(?=.*[\W])` para que al menos tenga un caracter no alfanumérico

6- `\S` para cualquier caracter

7- `$` Fin de expreción

Saludos